# Is it possible to change the font size or font colour of push notification message in react-native?

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I am not sure if this question can be asked here.I googled a lot but I didn't the answer I am looking for.

I am a `react-native` developer and don't have any knowledge about `android` native or `iOS` native.I heard from native developers that push notifications message can be formatted, like changing font size, font colour etc...

Is it possible to do same thing with react-native app?